# How to find Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova installed along with VS2015 RTM programatically?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

My requirement is to find programatically that whether Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova is installed along with VS2015 RTM installation by checking the installed location or through registry entry.

Am using C# code.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me understand what it is you're trying to do? Are you writing an extension to visual studio?

Comment: no. i just want to show whether apache cordova is installed or not

Comment: Show it where? For who? Why? What are you trying to solve?